# Start a specific tab of a tab layout (with switch cases) from different activity

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-tabs, tabactivity

I have this onClickListener on a card view of dashboard activity which will open a specific tab of a tab layout.
Calling it from dashboard activity to category activity. This is what I did inside onclicklistener.

```
        grocery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, CategoryActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("position", 2);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

This is my category activity

```
public class CategoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
public ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent == null) {
        extrasPosition = 0;
    } else {
        extrasPosition = intent.getIntExtra("position",0);
    }
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));
//display the desired fragment
    FragmentTransaction frt = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    frt.replace(R.id.container, mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(extrasPosition));
    frt.addToBackStack(null);
    frt.commit();

}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // returning current tabs using switch case
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                viewClothing tab0 = new viewClothing();
                return tab0;
            case 1:
                viewElectronics tab1 = new viewElectronics();
                return tab1;
            case 2:
                viewFurniture tab2 = new viewFurniture();
                return tab2;
            case 3:
                viewGrocery tab3 = new viewGrocery();
                return tab3;
            case 4:
                viewHardware tab4 = new viewHardware();
                return tab4;
            case 5:
                viewStationary tab5 = new viewStationary();
                return tab5;
            case 6:
                viewOthers tab6 = new viewOthers();
                return tab6;
                default:
                    return null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 7 total pages.
        return 7;
    }
}
}
```

What I want is to open the grocery tab which is case 3.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get `int` extra from `intent` you're sending. Then if it's not null you invoke `getItem(position)` with default 0 and if it's not you pass the position and display the desired fragment.

```
 public class CategoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
public ViewPager mViewPager;
public int extrasPosition;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);
    //get extra from intent;
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent == null) {
        extrasPosition = 0;
    } else {
        extrasPosition = intent.getIntExtra("position", 0);
    }

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));

    //display the desired fragment
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(extrasPosition);
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // returning current tabs using switch case
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                viewClothing tab0 = new viewClothing();
                return tab0;
            case 1:
                viewElectronics tab1 = new viewElectronics();
                return tab1;
            case 2:
                viewFurniture tab2 = new viewFurniture();
                return tab2;
            case 3:
                viewGrocery tab3 = new viewGrocery();
                return tab3;
            case 4:
                viewHardware tab4 = new viewHardware();
                return tab4;
            case 5:
                viewStationary tab5 = new viewStationary();
                return tab5;
            case 6:
                viewOthers tab6 = new viewOthers();
                return tab6;
                default:
                    return null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 7 total pages.
        return 7;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: still opening default tab.

Comment: @RishiRaj looked into viewpager docs....let's try instead of fragmenttransaction using  mViewPager.setCurrentItem(extrasPosition); (I editted the answer)

But first make sure in debug that your position is passed successfully with intent

Comment: and you don't need 0 here extrasPosition = intent.getIntExtra("position", 0); I noticed you added it in your code

Comment: its giving an error if I don't pass it that way, saying getIntentExtra(String, int) in Intent cannot be applied to (String).

Comment: yeah, it's default value you're right man. It's difficult sometimes to remember everything without the studio which helps with such things. Did you try check that you get right value from intent? and used  pager.setCurrentItem?

Comment: great, I 'm glad it helped. Please, kindly upvote and accept ))

Comment: please update your answer  with extrasPosition = intent.getIntExtra("position", 0);